# Css set a property for h2 to h6 for a specific class

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, inside different `<h>` tags.

I would like to apply some formatting to ALL `<h>` tags inside specifically to any  with **class cnt ONLY**.

At the moment I'm using the following CSS without success... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
<div class="cnt">
    <h1>Some Text.</h1>
    <h2>Some Text.</h2>
    <h3>Some Text.</h3>
    <h4>Some Text.</h4>
    <h5>Some Text.</h5>
    <h6>Some Text.</h6>
</div>


    h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 .cnt 
    {
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:700;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
.cnt h2, .cnt h3, .cnt h4, .cnt h5, .cnt h6 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

read up on [css specificity](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20speciifcy#hl=en&sa=X&ei=wQx3TvmaJoSt8QOQ1pDLDQ&ved=0CCMQvwUoAQ&q=css%20specificity&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=94658e94c5235901&biw=1680&bih=882)

Answer (score 2):

```
.cnt h1, .cnt h2, .cnt h3, .cnt h4, .cnt h5, .cnt h6 {
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

captainclam has the right answer, but just so you understand a little about why it didn't work, the following selector:

```
h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 .cnt
```

would represent something like the following:

```
<h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><div class="cnt"></div></h6></h5></h4></h3></h2>
```

(anything with class cnt could be put in h6 for it to apply)

@Ross, it had nothing to do with specificity; The selector was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div.cnt h1, div.cnt h2, div.cnt h3, div.cnt h4, div.cnt h5, div.cnt h6 
{
    /* ... */
}
```